# Why won't SQL Developer accept a JDK?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I downloaded Oracle 11g r2 and am trying to launch SQL Developer for the first time.  However, it is asking for a JDK path.  When I first tried a `java.exe` that I already had installed on my PC, SQL Developer said that it was not a JDK, so I tried the following steps, which have not yet resolved the problem.

1.) I went to [the oracle jdk download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and explicitly downloaded `jdk-8u-74-windows-x64,exe` shown below

2.) I then let the installer install the program to `C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8_74\`

3.) I next pointed the Oracle SQL Developer dialog box to the path of the `java.exe` in this new directory.

But Oracle SQL Developer just replaces the dialog box with a new empty dialog box.  This repeats every time that I try.

**Why can't Oracle SQL Developer accept this JDK?  What specific steps need to be taken to get Oracle SQL Developer to the point where it understands that it has a JDK and thus moves further into the launch process?**

A screen shot is at the following link:

http://s13.postimg.org/ilsqjdj1z/sql_developer_jdk.jpg

I would embed the url of the image into this view, but I need at least 10 reputation points to do that.  So please click the link to view the screen shot.

---

**Continuing Research:**

---

I repeated the steps above with JDK 6, Build 45, but am getting the same failed results.

I would ask this in chat, but I need at least 20 reputation points to talk in a chat room.

Comment: Don't point it to the exe but to the JDK root folder (e.g. C:\Programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_74).

Comment: @Alfabravo Thank you.  I just tried that.  The browse dialog box requires you to select a `java exe` file.  When I try to trick it by selecting one and then deleting the file in the resulting dialog box (shown in the link in the OP) to match your suggestion, clicking OK results in the same problem described in the OP.

Comment: Check that `%appdata%\SQL Developer\` folder exists and the config files are there, including product.conf, where the SetJavaHome parameter should contain the path to the JDK. (For SQLDev v4.1)

Comment: @Alfabravo I opened the run dialog box and typed `%APPDATA%` which opened up `AppData/Roaming/`, which did not have any folder for SQL Developer or for Oracle.  Similarly, the ``AppData/` folder did not contain any app folders, and only had subfolders for `Local`, `LocalLow`, and `Roaming`.  The `AppData/Local` folder did not contain an Oracle or SQL Developer subfolder.  The `AppData/LocalLow` folder did not contain a SQL Developer folder, but it did contain `AppData/LocalLow/Oracle/`, which only contained JDK and JRE stuff.  What do you suggest from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are installing on 64-bit windows, get the 64-bit SQL Dev.  It has the java built in, and so does not require the extra JDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you had a JRE, and not a JDK. Also, when it prompts for a path, don't select the Java.exe, instead you want the 'Java Home', for example: 
  C:\Program Files\Java\JDK1.8.0_60

Some more details [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/12/oracle-sql-developer-4-windows-and-the-jdk/)

Or, if [you're on a Mac](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/java-8-on-a-mac-with-sql-developer-4-1/).

Or, [if your 'java' moves on you](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/03/on-installs-and-updates-of-sql-developer/) - common on Mac's after an OS upgrade.